# Radopen Doesn't fire

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have to call a popup window using radopen. i did it a lot in the same project and it works fine also i did it in the same page and it works fine too but when i using radtoolbar something happens and the radopen doesn't fire.
here's my code :

```
<telerik:RadToolBar ID="GridToolBar" OnClientButtonClicking="clickHandler" dir="<%$ Resources: Main,Dir %>"
            OnButtonClick="GridToolBar_OnClick" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Main,ExportToExcel  %>"
                    runat="server" Value="Excel" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Image, Excel%>">
                </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Main,ExportToExcelML  %>"
                    runat="server" Value="ExcelML" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Image, ExcelML%>">
                </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Main,ExportToWord %>"
                    runat="server" Value="Word" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Image, Word%>">
                </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Main,ExportToCSV  %>"
                    runat="server" Value="CSV" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Image, CSV%>">
                </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Main,ExportToPDF %>"
                    runat="server" Value="PDF" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Image, PDF%>">
                </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Main,AddExistingUser %>" CssClass="<%$ Resources: Main,ToolbarButtonAlignment %>"
                    runat="server" Value="AddUser" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Image, RegisterUser%>" 
                </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadToolBar>
```

the last button should show a popup window using radopen. i used the javascript function calld clickhandler and here's the function :

```
 function clickHandler(sender, eventArgs) {
        if (eventArgs.get_item().get_value() == "AddUser") {
            alert("Welcome");
            radopen("Page_Popup.aspx", "RW");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

be informed that the alert message welcome is appeared to me.
and when i replace radopen with window.open it opens a new window.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postback from the click hides the RadWindow. You should cancel the postback, or use AJAX.

To test this set the AutoPostBack property of the RadToolBar to false, and remove the server side clck handler. If this works, then the postback is your issue.

To fix it you can either:

- use AJAX - add an AJAX setting where the toolbar is the initiator and the updated control (and add any other needed updated controls) but make sure that the RadWindow/RadWindowManager are not included in the partial postback
- OR - make sure you cancel the postback. The set_cancel(true) command from the other answers should do the trick
- OR - open the RadWindow from the server handler: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-opening-from-server.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
radopen("Page_Popup.aspx", "RW");
eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
return false;
```

Not sure but it might solve your problem.

If it opens the radwindow then your problem is your server-side click event i.e. `OnButtonClick="GridToolBar_OnClick"`

So, to resolve this, you need to open the RadWindow using server-side event `OnButtonClick="GridToolBar_OnClick"`

Comment: no. it doesn't work. i also tried to open it from code behind but no imapct. it just put # at the end of url

Comment: try to open it by removing OnButtonClick event for a while. Also have you placed any setting in RadAjaxmanager or RadAjaxManagerProxy for RadGrid? If yes then have you placed RadWindowManager or RadWindow in update controls tag? Can you put the HTML of RadWindow and RadGrid control?

Comment: i tried to remove the OnButtonClick event but nothing happened. and i am using it inside radajaxpanel in the master page. but as i said i am using another radopen in the same page in another tab and it works fine.